# Xbee S2C is resetting Arduino Uno

Tags: xbee

I have a coordinator radio hooked up to a sparkfun xbee shield, hooked up to an Uno. This is then hooked up to my computer. This coordinator talks with a number of xbee routers/end devices and sends them 6 commands to change the digital pins high or low on the corresponding xbees. The commands are always frame ID = 0, then the last (6th) command I send a 0x2 to save all the digital pins high or low at once.

The issue is that occasionally when the xbee receives all of the commands and saves them, the Uno will reset itself. (I can tell by the blinking LED on 13).

I have looked into it, and the best suggestion so far is to disable D7 on the receiving Xbee via XCTU. This unfortunately has not helped. Is there another reason that the arduino is resetting every couple of times I change the pins on the xbee? It doesn't happen every time, just once out of every 3-5 times...

Answer (score 0):

Bleh, I figured it out. Not only do I have to turn D7 off, I also have to hook a jumper between 5V and RST as shown here. 
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/xbee-shield-hookup-guide/all

Comment: It's OK to accept your own answer as the solution.